# A Poincaré-type inequality with logarithmic function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, sobolev-spaces

For any function $f(x)$ we denote $\bar{f}:=\frac{1}{\Omega}\int_\Omega f(x)\,dx$.
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded smooth domain and $u(x)> 0$ be a smooth function defined on $\Omega$. I want to know whether the following is true:
$$\int_\Omega |\ln u(x)-\ln \bar{u}|^2dx\le C\int_\Omega 
|\nabla \ln u(x)|^2dx,$$
for some $C$ independent of $u$.

I think this general result must be fault, is it true when $\Omega$ is convex?

If it is true for convex $\Omega$, I have a further question: use "$F$" instead of "$\ln$" which kinds $F$ support this type inequality.

Remark: I missed a condition that $u$ have an upper bound $M$, $C$ could depend on $M$.

Comment: I do not think an upper bound helps. Note that both sides of the inequality are unchanged if u is replaced by Ku. So if there is a constant that works if u is bounded above by M, that same constant will work for any u that is bounded above, and then a limit argument would extend it to unbounded u as in my counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

It is false for a ball. In three dimensions, consider $u=r^a$, where $a>-3$ and let $\Omega$ be the unit ball. We find $\bar u=3/(3+a)$. As a approaches -3, the right hand side of your inequality remains bounded, the left hand side does not.

Comment: Your answer is correct and very nice. Thank you. But I very sorry, I had make a mistake that what I really concern, there is one more condition: $u$  has a uniform upper bound $M$. Now I edit the problem.

Comment: The domain is bounded, why the left hand side of your example is unbounded?

Comment: Because $\tilde u\to\infty$ as $a\to -3$ and $|\ln u|^2$ remains integrable.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I alway keep $u\le M$ in my mind! Yes, you are right, but what I really concern, need $u$ has an upper bound.